# Streaming Video in .NET languages including C#

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming

It is one thing to stream a video to a html page and render the web page using a .NET Form and .NET Web Browser. My Question to you is whether it is possible to render or stream video to a video player rather than an embedded video in a html page. Is that called breaking in ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out MSDN and the DirectX api [Video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497(VS.85).aspx) object?

Comment: Thanks buddy. It is then not called breaking in.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'breaking in'?

Comment: It could be a standard thing to do DirectX programming to stream video, but from my own novice perspective, I connived to render video by other simpler .NET methods. I thought it was seemingly like breaking in to .NET framework. Now I know, it is not. We have the attitude of playing cricket here betweeen work hours. Would anybody be interested in the "Nerds Cricket Championship" ?

Comment: Stevo, do you think of rugby in betweeen computer tasks ? It is a game of a lot of pushing and shoving, very much like computer jobs.
By that I mean one could lose the job, if he is not the first one to get there ...... [testing and programming software and converting them into CDs]